# How to fix 403 response in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

http://prntscr.com/o56670

Please check the screenshot

I am using python 3 and using scrapy in my terminal.

fetch("https://angel.co/adil-wali")

When the link is requested, it responses with 403.

so i have changed and rotated user agent and robots obey false but still showing 403 response so this time i buy crawlera plan but crawlera still saying 523 response

Do you have any idea about why the request returns 403 instead of 200 response in scrapy shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding headers to your request:

```
fetch(
    "https://angel.co/adil-wali", 
    headers={
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
    }
)
```

With this approach, I was able to get Response 200 from the mentioned URL.